# Why does Async.StartChild return `Async<Async<'T>>`?

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, f#

I'm very new to F# and I've been reading *F# for Fun and Profit*. In the *Why use F#?* series, there's a [post](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/concurrency-async-and-parallel/) describing async code. I ran across the `Async.StartChild` function and I don't understand why the return value is what it is.

The example:

```ml
let sleepWorkflow  = async {
    printfn "Starting sleep workflow at %O" DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
    do! Async.Sleep 2000
    printfn "Finished sleep workflow at %O" DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
}

let nestedWorkflow  = async {

    printfn "Starting parent"
    let! childWorkflow = Async.StartChild sleepWorkflow

    // give the child a chance and then keep working
    do! Async.Sleep 100
    printfn "Doing something useful while waiting "

    // block on the child
    let! result = childWorkflow

    // done
    printfn "Finished parent"
}
```

My question is why shouldn't `Async.StartChild` just return `Async<'T>` instead of `Async<Async<'T>>`? You have to use `let!` twice on it. The [documentation](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-control-fsharpasync.html#StartChild) even states:

> This method should normally be used as the immediate right-hand-side of a let! binding in an F# asynchronous workflow [...] When used in this way, each use of StartChild starts an instance of childComputation and returns a completor object representing a computation to wait for the completion of the operation. When executed, the completor awaits the completion of childComputation.

In some testing, adding some calls to sleep, it seems that without the initial `let!` the child computation is never started.

Why have this return type / behavior? I'm used to C# where calling an `async` method will always "kick off" the task right away even if you don't `await` it. In fact, in C#, if the `async` method doesn't call any async code it will run synchronously.

Edit for clarification:

What is the advantage of this:

```ml
let! waiter = Async.StartChild otherComp // Start computation
// ...
let! result = waiter // Block
```

Compared to if `Async.StartChild` returned an `Async<'T>`:

```ml
let waiter = Async.StartChild otherComp // Start computation
// ...
let !result = waiter // Block
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is this: You start another async-computation (in the background) with `let wait = Async.StartChild otherComp` and you get the *waiter* back.

What that means is that `let! result = waiter` will *block* and wait for the result of your background-computation whenever you want.

if `Async.StartChild` would return a `Async<'t>` you would *wait* with `let! x = otherComp` right there and it would be just like a *normal* let! result = otherComp`

---

And yes F# Async-Workflows will only *start*  once you do something like `Async.Start...` or `Async.RunSynchronously` (it's not like a `Task` that usually runs as soon as you created it)

that's why in C# you can create a Task (`var task = CreateMyTask()`) at one point (that would be the `Async.StartChild` part) and then later use `var result = await task` to wait there for the result (that's the `let! result = waiter` part).

---

### Why `Async.StartChild` returns `Async<Async<'T>>` instead of `Async<'T>`

This is because the workflows started this way is supposed to behave like a *child*-task/process. When you **cancel** the containing workflow the *child* should be **canceled** as well.

So on a technical level the child-workflow needs access to the cancelation-token without you passing it explicitly and that is one thing the `Async`-Type handles in the background for you when you use `Bind` (aka `let!` here).

So it has to be this type in order for that passing of the cancelation-token to work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm still a little confused, would you mind editing to address my clarifying question?

Comment: Did - I hope this helps you out

Comment: Kismet! I was typing up an answer that provides the signature that the OP wants, and speculated that maybe the actual signature is due to cancelation requirements... just as you were adding your explanation. :)

Comment: @Carsten That helps, thanks. If I can just throw some language I only half understand, the `let!` is a monadic bind, the same way `<-` is in Haskell, so it _has_ to return that because that monad is wrapping values in a context. But the value in this case is itself an `Async<'T>` so that's why we need the return value we do. Right?

Comment: Don't know if I understand the question right - what I wanted to say is, that you expect the child-workflow to share the cancelation-token, that is hidden in the `Async<'T>` type of F#. The way the computational/async-Workflows are implemented pass that token to the parts where you use a `!` (yes those are mostly translated into Binds) - so it's not exactly because of the return type but because you want this *passing of tokens* to happen - if you want this in C# you have to pass the Tokens around yourself  (AFAIK)

Comment: @Carsten Yup! I think we're on the same page, I appreciate the help. The `Bind` is hiding the implementation the same way Haskell's `>>=` (also bind) operator hides extra data. The original `Async<'T>` is in a context.

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about this a bit and can't come up with a solid explanation. In fact, as a proof of concept, I was able to write a crude version of `StartChild` that has the behavior you want:

```
let myStartChild computation =

    let mutable resultOpt = None
    let handle = new ManualResetEvent(false)

    async {
        let! result = computation   // run the computation
        resultOpt <- Some result    // store the result
        handle.Set() |> ignore      // signal that the computation has completed
    } |> Async.Start

    async {
        handle.WaitOne() |> ignore   // wait for the signal
        handle.Dispose()             // cleanup
        return resultOpt.Value       // return the result
    }
```

I wrote a basic smoke test and it seems to work fine, so either I'm overlooking something important (maybe having to do with cancelation tokens?), or the answer to your question is that it doesn't have to be that way.

I'm not an `Async` expert by any means, so I'd love for someone with more knowledge than me to chime in.

**Update**: Based on Carsten's updated answer, I think we have a complete explanation: You can either:

- Have the signature you want, but without cancelation support, or
- Use the standard `Async<Async<'T>>` signature if you need cancelation.

The second version is more flexible, which is why it's in the standard library.